# Upload JUnit Test Results and Code Coverage to Sonar

Tags: android, ant, junit, code-coverage, sonarqube

I have an Android application that we have a project that is built using ant and then uploads the lint analysis results to Sonar server.  I have another test project that contains all the JUnit tests.  I want to upload the JUnit test results and code coverage to Sonar into the same Sonar project of the android app.  How do I do this in the ant build script, upload just the JUnit test results and code coverage?

```
<!-- Sample local host configuration -->
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="x" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="x" />

<!-- Define the SonarQube project properties -->
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="android-app" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="AndroidApp" />

<property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
<property name="sonar.modules" value="MyAndroidApp" />
<property name="sonar.profile" value="Android Lint" />

<property name="sonar.projectBaseDir" value="../MyAndroidApp" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="bin/classes" />
<property name="sonar.libraries" value="libs/*.jar, ../google-play-services_lib/libs/*.jar, ${sdk.dir}/platforms/${target}/android.jar" />
<property name="junit.tests.results" value="../MyAndroidAppJavaUnitTests/junit-output" />

<!-- Sets the sonar project version at runtime-->
<target name="sonar-set-project-version">
    <xpath input="${manifest.abs.file}" expression="/manifest/@android:versionName" output="sonar.projectVersion"/>
    <echo level="info">Setting sonar project version to: ${sonar.projectVersion}</echo>
</target>


<!-- Define the SonarQube target -->
<target name="sonar" depends="sonar-set-project-version">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="sonar-ant-task-*.jar" />
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Execute the SonarQube analysis -->
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
```

Comment: You Ant script has some errors, so this cannot work. For instance, "sonar.modules" is set to "MyAndroidApp", but you configure some weird parameters like "CarsLibrary.sonar.*" => "CarsLibrary" does not match any module defined in "sonar.modules"

Comment: Sorry typo on my part, in the middle of trying some things when I copy pasted...

Answer (score 1):

The procedure was explained by Olivier Gaudin a few years ago in a [Sonar blog post](http://www.sonarqube.org/reuse-in-sonar-unit-test-reports-generated-by-other-systems/)

As I have no Ant build, I'm not sure if this will work, but try to set the following parameters `sonar.junit.reportsPath=path/to/your/junit/report` and `sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports`. This should do the job.

Comment: Doesn't work just get some vague error  org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar